# Where do deploy wordpress site to share website in development with client?

Tags: wordpress, heroku, deployment

I am making a wordpress website and would like to share it with my client so that they can look at it. I can only do it remotely. I have done something similar on heroku with other frameworks and languages but cant find if and where to host wordpress site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put it in a hosting server (yours or external) supporting wordpress.

If it's your own, you need to have a fixed IP to make it accessible from the external world, or a service to associate a DNS to a variable IP if you don't have a fixed one.

If it is external, the hosting provider will take care of everything.  You'll find a lot of hosting providers supporting wordpress if you google it, as it's a common services these days.

Comment: I dont have a hosting server yet since its still in development and havent decided where to host it yet.

Comment: You need a hosting server on your own or external (at least temporary) to show your work if you want a completely functional test. The only other option is sending screen shots, but it's a poor show...  A shared hosting won't be expensive (I think)

Comment: Yep. looks like it. i didnt want to spend any money on it since its an internship but looks like no way out of it.

Comment: I've googled cheapest wordpress hosting and some prices are really good...  (one in UK 2.5 per month)  it's an investment but probably an opportunity for you!.  Could you mark the answer to this stackoverflow post to know it's an answer please?. Thanks!